# Multiple Search Text at the same time using Forms in Microsoft Access Database

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

In Access, I have a table of data.

I created a form which acts as a search engine for my data. On entering one search text at a time in the search box, the form works.

When I paste multiple search text (present as rows) in my search box, the forms don't work.
I want the option to paste up to 20 search elements at once in my search box and display all the corresponding results.

For instance, search text for one search at a time "7783-26-4".
Now, I wish to paste the entire column below as my search text

- 7783-26-4
- 13821-46-1
- 13075-28-0

I created a query for the form using a Query builder. For single search element the criteria is as follows:

```
Like "*" & [Forms]![MyFormName]![MySearchText] & "*"
```

I tried modifying the query for multiple search text as follows:

```
    [Field1] Like "*" & [Forms]![MyFormName]![MySearchText] & "*" 
AND [Field2] Like "*" & [Forms]![MyFormName]![MySearchText] & "*"
```

Also, my search text contains multiple fields. For example: Name, ID, Reference no, Code.

VBA code for one search element at a time.

```vb
Private Sub Clear_Click()

Me.SearchBox = ""
Me.Searchtext = ""
Me.Searchtext.SetFocus
Me.ListResult.Requery

End Sub

Private Sub SearchBox_Change()

Me.Searchtext = Me.SearchBox.Text
Me.ListResult.Requery

End Sub
```

Comment: Try with OR not AND: `[Field1] Like "*" & [...] & "*" OR [Field2] Like "*" & [...] & "*" `.

Comment: Hey Gustav. Excuse me for the late reply. Also, Thanks for your help. I tried using this option earlier although, the code needed more specification with respect to the search form. Anyways, it's figured out now. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you use only one text field for a each search then I would maybe do this:

Have two tables, the original containing the Data and then table that has the same structure but contains some criteria.

[image]

Now a query like this results the common data based on the ID:

[image]

then the SQL looks like this `SELECT Data.Name_, Data.ID, Data.RefNo, Data.Code FROM Temp INNER JOIN Data ON Temp.ID = Data.ID;`

Then have one main form and two subforms inside the main:
[image]

Then the code for the Search-button click event:

```
Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim qdfTemp As QueryDef
Dim qdfNew As QueryDef
Dim f As Field
Dim seachFieldName As String
Dim i As Long

Set dbs = CurrentDb
Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset("temp", dbOpenDynaset, dbReadOnly)

'Go to row 1 in temp table and check which search field has been filled using the form
rst.MoveFirst
For i = 0 To rst.Fields.Count - 1
    If Not IsNull(rst.Fields(i).Value) Then
        seachFieldName = rst.Fields(i).Name
        Exit For
    End If
Next

If Nz(seachFieldName, 0) <> 0 Then 'if data was found in one of the columns in temp table then create temporary QueryDef
    Set qdfTemp = dbs.CreateQueryDef("", _
        " SELECT Data.Name_, Data.ID, Data.RefNo, Data.Code" & _
        " FROM Temp INNER JOIN Data ON Temp." & seachFieldName & " = Data." & seachFieldName & ";")
    'Update the RecordSource for the lower subform to hold the results
    Me![Child1].Form.RecordSource = qdfTemp.SQL
End If
```

Now it should work like this:
[image]

I hope this helps!

Comment: Hey Mika O. Excuse me for the late reply. Thanks for your help, your answer helped me to figure out the problem to a certain extent.